# Session disappears unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, session

The site is a buy/sell site and the page the code comes from is the "add product" page.

The problem is that the session("change") becomes nothing by some reason, I can't find any errors. The payment.aspx have a button that sends me back to the page with a session("change").
The reason I see the problem is that when I try to edit something the category gets restetted to the first in the list. and when I debug I see that the session is nothing, though it should be something

Heres the code:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click
        If Not stats > 0 Then
            If Session("change") IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim dc As New DataClassesDataContext
                Dim getP = From prod In dc.Products _
                           Where prod.ProductID = CInt(Session("change")) _
                           Select prod

                If getP.Any Then
                    If rdbSell.Checked = True Then
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.BuySell = True
                    Else
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.BuySell = False
                    End If
                    If ddlSubSubcat.SelectedValue IsNot String.Empty Then
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.CategoryID = CInt(ddlSubSubcat.SelectedValue)
                    Else
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.CategoryID = CInt(ddlSubCat.SelectedValue)
                    End If

                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Content = txtContent.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.CountyID = CInt(ddlCounty.SelectedValue)
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.E_mail = txtEmail.Text
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Date = DateTime.Now
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Active = 0
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Alias = txtAlias.Text.Replace("'", "''")
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.ShowEmail = 0
                    Dim PreID As Integer = getP.FirstOrDefault.ProductID
                    If chkShowEmail.Checked = True Then
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.ShowEmail = 1
                    Else
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.ShowEmail = 0
                    End If
                    If chkShowPhone.Checked = True Then
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.ShowPhone = 1
                    Else
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.ShowPhone = 0
                    End If
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Headline = txtHeadline.Text
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Password = txtPassword.Text
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Phone = txtPhone.Text
                    getP.FirstOrDefault.Price = txtPrice.Text

                    If chkUnknown.Checked = True Then
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.YearModel = String.Empty
                    Else
                        getP.FirstOrDefault.YearModel = ddlYear.SelectedValue
                    End If

                    For Each item In libPictures.Items
                        Dim i As String = item.ToString
                        Dim imagecheck = From img In dc.Pictures _
                                         Where img.Name = i And img.ProductID = CInt(Session("change")) _
                                         Select img

                        If imagecheck.Any Then
                        Else
                            Dim img As New Picture
                            img.Name = item.ToString

                            img.ProductID = CInt(Session("change"))
                            dc.Pictures.InsertOnSubmit(img)
                            dc.SubmitChanges()
                        End If
                    Next

                    dc.SubmitChanges()

                    Session.Remove("change")
                    Response.Redirect("~/precheck.aspx?id=" + PreID.ToString)
                End If
            Else
                Dim dc As New DataClassesDataContext
                Dim prod As New Product
                If rdbSell.Checked = True Then
                    prod.BuySell = True
                Else
                    prod.BuySell = False
                End If
                If ddlSubSubcat.DataValueField IsNot String.Empty Then
                    prod.CategoryID = CInt(ddlSubSubcat.SelectedValue)
                Else
                    prod.CategoryID = CInt(ddlSubCat.SelectedValue)
                End If

                prod.Content = txtContent.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
                prod.CountyID = CInt(ddlCounty.SelectedValue)
                prod.E_mail = txtEmail.Text
                prod.Date = DateTime.Now
                prod.Active = 0
                prod.Alias = txtAlias.Text.Replace("'", "''")
                prod.ShowEmail = 0
                If chkShowEmail.Checked = True Then
                    prod.ShowEmail = 1
                Else
                    prod.ShowEmail = 0
                End If
                If chkShowPhone.Checked = True Then
                    prod.ShowPhone = 1
                Else
                    prod.ShowPhone = 0
                End If
                prod.Headline = txtHeadline.Text
                prod.Password = txtPassword.Text
                prod.Phone = txtPhone.Text
                prod.Price = txtPrice.Text

                If chkUnknown.Checked = True Then
                    prod.YearModel = String.Empty
                Else
                    prod.YearModel = ddlYear.SelectedValue
                End If

                dc.Products.InsertOnSubmit(prod)
                dc.SubmitChanges()
                Dim PreID As Integer = prod.ProductID

                For Each item In libPictures.Items
                    Dim img As New Picture
                    img.Name = item.ToString

                    img.ProductID = prod.ProductID
                    dc.Pictures.InsertOnSubmit(img)
                    dc.SubmitChanges()
                Next
                Session.Remove("change")
                Response.Redirect("./precheck.aspx?id=" + PreID.ToString, False)
            End If
        End If
        stats = 0
        'Catch ex As Exception
        'End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post your complete code here. Try to construct a short, self-contained example that demonstrates just the issue you are experiencing. (See http://sscce.org for details.)

Comment: well, thats not even 1/6 of the code, i guess i can delete some parts... But sience i dont know the problem i posted the things i felt were important. Ill edit it to a shorter version

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I think you misunderstood me: It's not about removing stuff that you *think is irrelevant*. It's about removing *as much stuff as possible while the error still occurs*. So, try removing, for example, `prod.E_mail = txtEmail.Text`. Does the error still occur? Yes? Then continue removing stuff. Once you've reached a state where no more lines can be removed without the error disappearing, post the code here.

Comment: Where do you set Session("Change")?  Are you sure it's not just your session timing out and getting reset?

Comment: I set it if you click the back button on the payment.aspx page... wich you go to when you press the accept button on this page. Also, the session is 20 minutes long, and this happens every time, regardless of time... Only way for it to reset is through an error?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how the application is managing session state. If your session state is managed `InProc` then if the application pool is recycled then all your session information will be lost. If that is happening then it could be a good option to store session state in SQL Server which will persist between app pool recycling.

More info:

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

[ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)

Comment: Well, i havent specified anything, so i guess its inproc.. But why is the server resetting the session?

Comment: That's a whole other question and could be because of a range of IIS configuration/threshold issues. Try changing the state management method and seeing if the problem is resolved. If you want to diagnose the recycling then you'd have to dig more into IIS config options.

Comment: Stupid of me, forgot to mention, running this in visual studio. and my localhost uses cassini.

Comment: Then I would suggest deploying it to an IIS server and seeing what happens there. It could well be not this issue, and something else in the code, but you need to be able to rule out one thing at a time.